# Proving a set to be a Vectorspace

Tags: vector-spaces

lately I came across this exercise on vectorspaces, and although I do understand why the set is a vectorspace, I lack the mathematical skill to know how to formulate a proof.

This was the exercise:

> Let S be the set of all sequences $(a_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ of real numbers
>   satisfying the recurrence relation $$ a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_{n} $$
>   Show that the (term-wise) sum of two sequences from S is again in S
>   and that any (term-wise) scalar multiple of a sequence from S is again
>   in S. Finally show that S (with this addition and scalar
>   multiplication) is a real vector space.

Would anybody know how to formulate a proof?

Comment: The question tells you explicitly what to do. Just give it a try!

Comment: You need to go back to the definition of vector spaces.

Comment: It may help to consider how the first two questions (sum and multiple) are related to the last

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_n = a_n + b_n$, where $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are in $S$. This means that $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ and $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n -2}$, so we have
$$
\begin{align}
c_n &= a_n + b_n \\\\
&= a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + b_{n-1} + b_{n -2}\\\\
 &= a_{n-1} +b_{n-1} +a_{n-2} + b_{n -2} \\\\
&= c_{n-1} + c_{n-2}
\end{align}
$$
and therefore $\{c_n\}$ is also in $S$. (Can you see why we can conclude this?)

Similarily, let $\{d_n\}$ be in $S$. We then have, for the sequence $\{e_n\}$ where $e_n = r\cdot d_n$ with $r$ a real number, that
$$
e_n = r\cdot d_n = r(d_{n-1} + d_{n-2}) = r\cdot d_{n-1} + r\cdot d_{n-2} = e_{n-1} + e_{n-2}
$$
so we have that $\{e_n\}$ is in $S$.

Now, the details on how to check that $S$ is a real vector space depends on what your book's definition of a real vector space is. But it usually boils down to checking the two things we have already checked, to confirm that there is a zero-vector, and that every vector has an inverse (i.e. negative). In addition, you might be required to check that something like the following holds, for any two vectors $\mathbf a, \mathbf b$ and any two scalars $r, s$:
$$
(r + s)(\mathbf a + \mathbf b) = r\mathbf a + r\mathbf b + s\mathbf a + s\mathbf b
$$
as well as
$$
r(s\mathbf a) = (rs)\mathbf a
$$
Doesn't your book have any examples where they take some set with an addition and scalar multiplication and check whether it is a vector space? It should follow this one pretty closely, only with different equations, since the set is defined differently.